# What is the easiest way to authenticate a site user in browser extension

Tags: authentication, browser, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, browser-extension

So, I've made a simple site with login form that stores user login and password hash in site's database.

Now I want to be able to know if a user is logged in on my site and what is his login/user id.

I've read that sending login and password from extension considered a bad practice. Auth2 is not very simple either.

Can you please tell me the easy way to do this?

Comment: The easiest is probably StackOverflow's [dance authentication](https://stackoverflow.blog/2017/03/30/stack-overflow-unveils-next-steps-computer-security/).

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question.  When you say you "want to be able to know if a user is logged in..." do you mean you want a browser extension to know?  Assuming you're the author of both the site and the extension, it should be a simple matter of designing the site so there's an element (ideally with an `id` attribute) that contains this information (maybe in `data-*` attributes), and a content script in the extension that accesses that information.

Comment: @Lori
I'm the author of the site and the extension. I want to be able to send user specific data to extension only for users who logged in to my site.